# How to Update DocuSign Envelope Document

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex, docusignapextoolkit

I have DocuSign set which sends PDF to docuSign for Signing. My requirement is to Update the Document of a particular envelop so that it will save cost of generating new envelope every time user make changes to actual document that has to be signed.

I am looking for some code reference if anyone has.

Comment: Do you need to update only document tab values or the whole document

Answer (score 0):

If no signers have actually signed the particular document in the envelope, then you can replace that specific document using the API.

In REST, this would be a PUT /documents or PUT /{documents/documentId}.  See "EnvelopeDocuments -> update" or "EnvelopeDocuments -> updateList".

You will need to add the tabs as well.